# Which verb is used to translate the "return" when returning an item for a refund?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes

If I want to bring something back to a store, do I use *rapporter, rendre,* or *retourner* to express that?

For example, *je voudrais rapporter cette huile d'olive...*

Or is there another expression I'm unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 5):

Having worked in retail in France, the word for a return is in fact *retour*, as in

> Je m'occupe des retours

However, you would not use the verb *retourner*, but indeed *rapporter*, as in

> Rapportez cette paire de chaussures demain et je m'occuperai du retour

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't say: 'Ce vêtement ne me va pas, je vais le retourner et prendre la taille au-dessus'. I would say '[...] je vais le rapporter [...]'. But still, as you wrote, we talk about 'retours'.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *retourner*.

*Rapporter* means to bring something back, but not necessarily to give it back.

Stores here in Quebec refer to their *Politique de retour*

Answer (score 0):

I think the most used verbs in France are *rendre* or *rapporter*.

Answer (score 0):

*Retourner* and *renvoyer* are good options to express the idea of bringing something back to store.

Use *renvoyer* if you make something back by any delivery or transport service (for example, if you receive an incomplete package).
*Retourner* can be used in any case.